# Opacity in Gimp changed automatically to 0

Tags: gimp, transparency

I have a problem in GIMP with the opacity of a layer. 
When I change the opacity of a layer(e.g opacity is 40) and go to another layer, the previous one's opacity goes automatically to 0. 
Does someone knows how can I fix this problem? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If it is a color-indexed image (typically, loaded from GIF), then this could be expected, since GIF doesn't support partial opacity, so in color-indexed mode pixels are either fully opaque or fully transparent. Convert the image to RGB (`Image>Mode>RGB`) to avoid this, but if you export to GIF again you may not get what you expect.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I have no gif images and my image is in RGB mode. I reinstalled GIMP but there is still no change. :/

Comment: Can you change your question and describe what you are doing in reproducible steps? Preferably with a sample image to start from.